# Opening .doc files in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ms-office

Can I open a .doc file and get that file's contents using Ruby?

Comment: Hello Jason, your question is open since a very long time, have you found a solution ? would you like to accept one of the answers ?

Answer (score 11):

If you only need the plain text content, you might want to have a look at [Yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu). It's a gem whichs acts as a wrapper for Apache TIKA and it supports a variety of document formats which includes the following:

- Microsoft Office OLE 2 and Office Open XML Formats (.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx)
- OpenOffice.org OpenDocument Formats (.odt, .ods, .odp)
- Apple iWorks Formats
- Rich Text Format (.rtf)
- Portable Document Format (.pdf)

Answer (score 10):

The gem docx is very simple to use

```
require 'docx'

puts Docx::Document.open('test.docx')
```

or

```
d = Docx::Document.open('test.docx')
d.each_paragraph do |p|
  puts p
end
```

you can find it at https://github.com/chrahunt/docx and install it by `gem install docx`

docx however doesn't support .doc files (word 2007 and earlier), then you can use the WIN32OLE like this:

```
require 'win32ole'

begin
  word = WIN32OLE.connect('Word.Application')
  doc = word.ActiveDocument
rescue
  word = WIN32OLE.new('word.application')
  path_open = 'C:\Users\...\test.doc' #yes: backslashes in windows
  doc = word.Documents.Open(path_open)
end

word.visible = true
doc.Sentences.each { |x| puts x.text }
```

Comment: can u write the gem name, which are used in your code example?

Comment: you can find it at https://github.com/chrahunt/docx and install it by gem install docx

Comment: Thank, I'm trying now! Have a little problem with nokogiri parsing: "Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Undefined namespace prefix: //w:document//w:body//w:p"

Comment: But how about parsing ".doc" MS Word 2004 files?

Comment: Now, I see an error - unknown OLE server: `Word.Application' :(

Comment: maybe it's because I havn't installed office on my virtual machine... I'm installing now.

Comment: "unknown OLE server: `Word.Application'" error was because I hadn't MS_Office installed on my laptop. Now everything is fine!

Comment: Unfortunatelly, reading .doc with win32ole example fails every 4-5 times, and ruby crashes... I don't know what's a problem(( "WIN32OLERuntimeError:"

Comment: probably the document itself has errors ? do you close word after running the script (see in task manager) Otherwise you could first translate it to .rtf and then use a gem that writes tot that or translate to .docx and use my first approach. with win32ole thsi is possible, i think i have some script hanging around that does just that

Comment: A create questoin about my problem with error logs and description: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033633/read-ms-word-doc-file-with-ruby-and-win32ole Please, help me if you can...(((

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes and No

In Ruby you can do something like:

```
thedoc = `externalProgram some_file`
```

And so what you need is a good *externalProgram.*

You could look at the [software library *wv*](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/) or the (apparently not recently updated) [program *antiword.*](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) I imagine there are others.  *OpenOffice* can read doc files and export text files, so driving OO via the CLI will probably also work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, this will work:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/classes/WIN32OLE.html

Answer (score 1):

I recently dealt with this in a project and found that I wanted a lighter-weight library to get the text from .doc, .docx and .pdf files. [DocRipper](https://github.com/pzaich/doc_ripper) uses a combination of Antiword, grep and Poppler/pdftotext command-line tools to grab the text contents from files and return them as a utf-8 string.

```
dr = DocRipper::TextRipper.new('/path/to/file')
dr.text
=> "Document's text"
```