# Convert Excel and Word files to PDF Using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to convert Excel with multiple sheets and Word files to PDF format as a single file using Ruby.

Is there any Script/Gems/Plugins available to achieve this?

Comment: This is an extremely convoluted topic. You should narrow down what you want to achieve. Which version of XLS, and DOC, complexity of the documents etc. Given that even Word occasionally has problems rendering old word files (not even speaking of Open/LibreOffice), you may be in for a lot of fun...

Comment: I love this topic, it's extremely useful.

Comment: Did you finally manage a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can use libreconv

https://github.com/ricn/libreconv

You'll need to install libre office on your server, which is straightforward.

Comment: It works fine on local but gives following error on Ubuntu server:

`Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

Comment: That sounds like it can't find the input file, can you post your code?

Comment: I have a "document.docx" file and want to convert to "tempfile.pdf" in the same directory, code is given below:

`Libreconv.convert("document.docx", 'tempfile.pdf', '/usr/bin/soffice')`

Answer (score 3):

There is not a Gem doing all the job. but you can combine some:

1. For excel files - read data using roo GEM - http://roo.rubyforge.org/
2. For word files [Opening .doc files in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195001/opening-doc-files-in-ruby)
3. Convert the data readed in previous steps into html.
4. Then convert it to pdf using: https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit

Comment: i want the pdf files same as in excel with the data and styles, if we go with roo gem then we have to create with our own