# Read document (.doc) with images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docsplit

I need to read document texts with ruby and then perform some operations on their contents. Some of these documents include images that I need to upload to my server and later show the data with images. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

I'm thinking of using `doc_ripper`/`docsplit`, but `ripper` doesn't talk about images extraction, and `docsplit` seems to only take a screenshot of the entire page.

If this is not possible, I am fine with a way to recover the image file name in the right position, so then I can extract the file and upload it manually.

Comment: what kind of documents?

Comment: .doc files , If this is not possible, at least to recover the IMG file name in the position , so maybe I can extract the file manually and upload it to the server

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195001/opening-doc-files-in-ruby

Comment: read that yesterday and doesnt talk about image managing , thanks by the way (and thanks for your - too , lol)