# view docx in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docx

I'm totally beginer and I have a problem with displaying file .docx in Ruby on Rails. I must show file .docx on browser, but it have error that "File /home/tho/workspace/file-mana/app/assets/demo.docx not found"

This is files_controller.rb

```js
class FilesController < ApplicationController  

  def index
  end
  
  def show
    require "docx"  
    doc = Docx::Document.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/demo.docx")
    doc.paragraphs.each do |p|
      puts p.to_html
    end
  end

end
```

This is my routes:

```js
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "static_pages#home"
  get '/show', to: 'files#show'
  resources :folders
  resources :files
end
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ShowFile</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'show' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use gem 'docx', '~> 0.2.07'`

Answer (score 0):

Put your demo.docx file in public folder and try below code:

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController  

  def index
  end

  def show
    require "docx"  
    doc = Docx::Document.open("#{Rails.root}/public/demo.docx")
    doc.paragraphs.each do |p|
      puts p.to_html
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I tried it and got a new error "Zip end of central directory signature not found". I guess RoR think that my docx file is zipped file, but I don't know why. Can you help me?

Comment: Save your demo.doc file as a .docx and try again.

Comment: I find only gem for docx. Morever, my subject is show docx files, not doc files

Comment: check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195001/opening-doc-files-in-ruby for help

Comment: I use Ubuntu, so It seem don't support win32ole

Comment: try `gem 'rubysl-win32ole'`